# How to check and compare Python versions in Powershell

Tags: python, powershell, version

I am trying to check and allow only certain versions of Python via Powershell. I am getting the current Python version, but I cannot check e.g. if version if older than 2.7, but not 3.

EDIT: Found in another SO question, I use a simple return that does not provide numeric result. It is `& python -V 2>&1`

Comment: What is your code to check the current Phython version?

Comment: Just added the code, sorry for missing it.

Comment: If you are testing an executable, you could use `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("C:\python.exe").FileVersion` to retrieve the file version.

Comment: I have tried that, but it does not return the file version. Apparently even the executable properties do not have the version listed. The command you suggest returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

```
If(($PythonVersion -gt 2.7) -and ($PythonVersion -lt 3))
{
  Do Something
}
Else
{
  Report Failure
}
```

You really need to include your code..

Comment: I am sorry I didn't, but the code I am using returns a string (as it seems) so it didn't look helpful. I added the code.